# JPQL Não esta reconhecendo o parâmetro

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, jpql

estou precisando realizar uma consulta utilizando JPQL ou método de palavras chaves do Spring-data. O problema é que o parâmetro inserido na consulta esta sendo ignorado, ainda não consegui identificar a causa disso.

Como o método findByDescricão esta ignorando o parâmetro (descricao) a consulta esta retornando todos os elementos do banco de dados referentes a esta tabela, sem critério nenhum.

O código do Repository mostra o método que esta com problema, apesar de ele estar utilizando a metodologia de palavra chave, eu também tentei utilizando JPQL:

```
@Query ("SELECT obj FROM Categoria obj WHERE descricao LIKE %:descricao%")
    List<Categoria> findByDescricao(@Param("descricao") String descricao);
```

O resultado foi o mesmo. Abaixo segue o código das classes envolvidas. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Classe @Resource

```
  import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;

    import javax.validation.Valid;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

    import com.eclodir.voucomprei.model.dto.CategoriaDTO;
    import com.eclodir.voucomprei.model.entity.Categoria;
    import com.eclodir.voucomprei.service.CategoriaService;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping (value="/categorias")
    public class CategoriaResource {

        @Autowired
        CategoriaService categoriaService;

        @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<List<CategoriaDTO>> findByDescricao (@RequestParam (value="descricao", defaultValue="") String descricao) {
            List<CategoriaDTO> categoriasDTO = new ArrayList<>();
            categoriasDTO = categoriaService.findAll();
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(categoriasDTO);
        }

    }
```

A segunda classe (@Service):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.eclodir.voucomprei.exception.ObjectNotFoundException;
import com.eclodir.voucomprei.model.dto.CategoriaDTO;
import com.eclodir.voucomprei.model.entity.Categoria;
import com.eclodir.voucomprei.repository.CategoriaRepository;
import com.eclodir.voucomprei.service.interfaces.CategoriaServiceInterface;

@Service
public class CategoriaService implements CategoriaServiceInterface {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CategoriaService.class);

    @Autowired
    CategoriaRepository categoriaRepository;


    @Override
    public List<CategoriaDTO> findByDescricao(String descricao) {
        List<Categoria> categorias = categoriaRepository.findByDescricaoContaining(descricao);
        if (categorias.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Categoria não encontrada");
        }
        List<CategoriaDTO> categoriasDTO = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Categoria categoria : categorias) {
            categoriasDTO.add(toDTO(categoria));
        }
        return categoriasDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public Categoria fromDTO(CategoriaDTO categoriaDTO) {
        Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
        categoria.setDescricao(categoriaDTO.getDescricao());
        return categoria;
    }

    @Override
    public CategoriaDTO toDTO(Categoria categoria) {
        CategoriaDTO categoriaDTO = new CategoriaDTO();
        categoriaDTO.setId(categoria.getId());
        categoriaDTO.setDescricao(categoria.getDescricao());
        return categoriaDTO;
    }


}
```

A interface (Repository):

```
package com.eclodir.voucomprei.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.eclodir.voucomprei.model.entity.Categoria;

@Repository
public interface CategoriaRepository extends JpaRepository<Categoria, Long> {

    List<Categoria> findByDescricaoContaining(@Param("descricao") String descricao);
}
```

obs.: A classe Categoria possui somente os campos Long id, String descricao.

Comment: Um chute, ja tentou mudar sua string para: `@Query ("SELECT obj FROM Categoria obj WHERE obj.descricao LIKE '%:descricao%'")` onde a _descricao_ faz parte do _obj_ e o seu parâmetro dentro de `' '` por ser `String`

Comment: Tenta ativar os logs do Hibernate e ver qual consulta está sendo gerada.

Comment: Acabei de tentar Paulo, o mesmo resultado. O Log Leonardo: Hibernate: 
    select
        categoria0_.id as id1_0_,
        categoria0_.descricao as descrica2_0_,
        categoria0_.dt_insert as dt_inser3_0_,
        categoria0_.dt_update as dt_updat4_0_ 
    from
        categoria categoria0_
É como se ele não reconhecesse a cláusula where.

Comment: Tente: `"SELECT c FROM Categoria c WHERE c.descricao LIKE CONCAT('%',:descricao,'%')"`

Comment: Descobri, o problema estava na classe do Resource. O método não estava apontado para a consulta correta, ele estava apontando findAll() por isso o erro. Fiz a correção e já esta funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método da classe abaixo estava apontando para o método de pesquisa errado, por isso não estava funcionando a busca parametrizada:

public class CategoriaResource {

```
    @Autowired
    CategoriaService categoriaService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<CategoriaDTO>> findByDescricao (@RequestParam (value="descricao", defaultValue="") String descricao) {
        List<CategoriaDTO> categoriasDTO = new ArrayList<>();
        categoriasDTO = categoriaService.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(categoriasDTO);
    }

}
```

Como podem ver ele estava apontando para o `findAll()` e não para o `findByDescricao(String descricao)` feito a correção, funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: você pode aceitar sua própria resposta como a correta :)